# Pass class type as argument with subtype

Tags: java, generics

How can i create an instance of the given generic type class with a subtype `Class<Foo<Bar>> type = ?`?

Its easy for simple generic such as: `Class<Foo> type = Foo.class;` but how to do this here?

```
final Class<Foo<Bar>> type = null; // ???
```

We cannot do something like `Foo<Bar>.class` which is possible in c# as far as i know.

I want to use this type in a generic function which works for all simple generics but not if nested.

```
Foo<Bar> fooBar = getRecord(type, 1);

static T get(Class<T> type, int id)
{
    // load from database
    return session.get(type, id);
}
```

**Complex example**

The production example is more complex having a DAO class with many methods that rely on the generic type.

```
interface Entity {}
class Foo<T extends Entity> extends Entity {}
class Bar extends Entity {}

class EntityDAO<T extends Entity> 
{
    Class<T> type;
    Session session;

    public EntityDAO(Class<T> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T get(int id)
    {
        return session.get(type, id);
    }
}

public class TestSession
{
    public <T> T get(final Class<T> type, final int id)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        return null;
    }
```

}

```
void static main(String[] args)
{
    final Class<Foo<Bar>> type = null; 

    // how to set type here?
    EntityDAO<Foo<Bar>> fooBarDAO = new EntityDAO<>(type);

    Foo<Bar> entity = fooBarDAO.get(1);

}
```

Currently i am just using the main type `Foo.class` loosing the `Bar.class` information for the DAO.

Comment: You'll need either a TypeToken (which can store the generic type info for you, a la `TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>`), or you'll need to send the generic paremeter as well e.g. `getRecord(Foo.class, Bar.class, 1);`. This is a limitation of java's generics. If you can provide a more concrete example, there may be alternative solutions.

Comment: If you have an instance of this type you could cast it to the specific class: `(Class<Foo<Bar>>) foo.getClass();`. But note that depending on how you want to implement this, it might not be any use in your case.

Comment: @Rogue the `TypeToken` is a nice example, which will need some factoring but will consider this. I edited the question with a second more complex example.

Comment: @Rogue I enhanced my example and using the `TypeToken` does not work cause in my `EntityDAO` i still pass the type as an argument to the constructor so the token just delegates the problem. The moment i need the class as a "variable" i am stuck.

Comment: @Japhei your first comment was correct answer and it works so you can add it as an answer. At runtime the `<Bar>` information is lost but it does not matter cause i only need the main `Foo` entity to access database entity table. Just for cleaner code i need `Foo<Bar>`. A alternate solution is to add constructor `public <V extends T> EntityDAO(Class<V> type)` and do casting inside and just pass `Foo.class`. I removed my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of this type you could cast it to the specific class:

```
Foo<Bar> foo = new Foo<>();
type = (Class<Foo<Bar>>) foo.getClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

With any workaround using `Class<Foo<Bar>> type;` as a variable the `<Bar>` is lost at runtime but still we can achieve the `EntityDAO` class to be as generic to support `Foo<Bar>` for easier code allow type to extend `T` inside the constructor / method and cast like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <V extends T> TestDAO(final Class<V> type)
{
    this.type = (Class<T>) type;
}
```

Then use it:

```
void static main(String[] args)
{
    // <Bar> information lost at runtime but not important
    EntityDAO<Foo<Bar>> fooBarDAO = new EntityDAO<>(Foo.class);

    // dao perfectly generic for Foo<Bar>
    Foo<Bar> entity = fooBarDAO.get(1);
}
```

This way we can use it without a dummy instance as @Japhei stated in his comment (which works with the original code) but not always a dummy instance is easy to create or available.